# how to parse with AngleSharp table in div with role tabpanel?

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing, anglesharp

I have HTML like this:

```
<table class="class_name1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Some th </th> 
            <td>Info</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i try do do this:

var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("div#bond_1.tab-pane.active > td");

```
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            list.Add(item.TextContent);
        }
```

I get empty list. 
I'll be very grateful for any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The table is contained in the div with role tabpanel.

Comment: What is the connection from the HTML to the provided C# code? Neither the class name nor and of the structure appears.

Comment: Also your selector does not make any sense. After a document has been constructed it is impossible to have a TD as a direct child of a div. Divisions need to be inside rows, which need to be inside container (tbody, thead, ...) which need to be inside tables. If not available the parser will insert these...